# Find number of pairs with difference larger than or equal to given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

I have a array/dict(HashMap) of positive integers.
I need to find the number of pairs that have a absolute difference greater or equal to a given number, K.

```
import random
import time

#given number
k =  4

# List of 2,00,000 random numbers in range 0-1000
strength = [random.randrange(0,1000) for x in range(200000)]  
strength.sort()

# start clock
start1 = time.clock()

n = len(strength)

# count keeps track of number of pairs found
count = 0

for x in range(n):
    for y in range(x,n):

        if abs(strength[x] - strength[y]) >= k:
            # if found, all number from this point to the end will satisfy
            count += n-y
            # So no need to go to the end
            break

end1 = time.clock()
print(count)
print(end1-start1)
```

All the answers I find are for pairs less than or equal to a given number.

I need to find the number of pairs that have a absolute difference greater or equal to a given number, K.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @hatchet edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Note that the total number of pairs is `n * (n - 1) / 2`, so if you can find the number of pairs with difference less than `K`, the number of pairs with difference greater than `K` is just `n * (n - 1) / 2 - num_pairs_with_diff_less_than_K`

The solution you provide is also correct (and well documented). If your question is how to adapt it to your case, then all you need to do is to use values of your `HashMap` (sorted) instead of the `strength` array.

Comment: That's another problem I have, I cannot find a solution that only include pairs strictly less than K, everything I find or am able to code contains the equal case as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 2 item combinations of the array and then filter / reduce them according to the difference.

One might do the job in JavaScript as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.combinations = function(n){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p.concat(n > 1 ? a.slice(i+1).combinations(n-1).map(e => (e.push(c),e))
                                                 : [[c]]),[]);
};

function getAcordingToDiff(a,d){
  return a.combinations(2)
          .reduce((p,c) => Math.abs(c[0]-c[1]) >= d ? (p.push(c),p) : p  ,[]);
}

var arr = Array(30).fill().map((_,i) => i+1); // array from [1,...,30]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getAcordingToDiff(arr,25))); // diff >= 25
```

**Explanation:**

So in the heart of the above code obviously lies the `Array.prototype.combinations` function. For those who are not familiar with JS, this is just an ordinary function that we define under the Array object's prototype (so that now every array has access to this function like `arr.combinations(n)`) But let's use a more expressive language and refactor the above combinations array method into a generic function.

```
function combinations(a,n){
  var sa;
  return a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
                    if (n > 1) sa = combinations(a.slice(i+1), n-1).map(e => (e.push(c),e));
                    else sa = [[c]];
                    return p.concat(sa);
                  },[]);
}
```

So as you will notice `combinations(a,n)` is a recursive function which takes an array `a` and items count `n`. It works on the basis of keeping the first item of the input array and recursively invoking itself with one item shorter array, `combinations(a.slice(i+1), n-1)`, and with one less items count up until `n` decrements to 1 in which case it starts it's return cycle with whatever remains from the input array and each item is wrapped in an array, `sa = [[c]]`.

So on the return cycle of the recursive calls we take the resulting array and push the kept first element (remember -> It works on the basis of keeping the first item of the input array) into each item of the returned array (remember -> ...and each item is wrapped in an array, `sa = [[c]]`).

So that's it... You should be able to figure out yourself the details.

However in our application we are given an array of numbers and requested to obtain only the 2 item combinations with a certain difference. In this particular case we don't need to calculate all combinations and then filter them. We can do this on the way constructing our combinations. As the required difference value `d` gets bigger this will bring in a huge gain over filtering afterwards method, since now as `d` gets bigger we are eliminating more and more of the two item combinations, even before we generate them. And... let's hard-wire our code to work with 2 items only and merge everything in a single function. The performance results are below;

```js
function getCombosWithDiff(a, d, n = 2){
  var sa;
  return a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
                    if (n > 1) sa = getCombosWithDiff(a.slice(i+1), d, n-1).reduce((r,e) => Math.abs(e[0]-c) > d ? (e.push(c),r.push(e),r)
                                                                                                                 : r, []);
                    else sa = [[c]];
                    return p.concat(sa);
                  },[]);
}

var arr = Array(100).fill().map((_,i) => i+1);
 result = getCombosWithDiff(arr,89);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

So that's it. I have tried the above code to list the 2 items combinations each with diff greater than 10 from an array of 1000 items. It takes like 5000 msecs in Chrome and 14000 msecs in FF. However as mentioned above, the more the diff value `d` gets bigger, the shorter it takes. e.g same array with diff 900 would resolve in just 1100msecs with Chrome and in 4000msecs with FF.

You can test and play [here](https://repl.it/ELZY/1)

Comment: @redus Can you tell me what you did in a bit more simpler language because I don't know JS and I need to code this in python...

Comment: @duh You have to be able to get the 2 item combinations of the input array first. I am sure there are many examples in Python doing this. Then all you have to do is to reduce / filter the ones with the difference greater than or equal to the given `d` value. I will explain the combinations function a few hours later because now i have leave the office.

Comment: @redus sure sure, take your time. Do you mean to say that make all possible 2 item combinations of the array? and then check if the difference between the 2 numbers is greater than or equal to the given d value?

Comment: @duh I tried to explain the algorithm and finally packed all job in a single function. In my final code I am finding the combinations with right amount  diff on the run while generating the combinations array. All explained in the extended part of the answer.

Comment: @redus the length of my array will be around 2,00,000 numbers and I have to get this under 5 sec.

Comment: @duh Yes you have 200K or 2M items but they are in the range 0-1000 so there are many duplicates and their combination wouldn't be any different than the combinations of a unique value items array of size 1000 like `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...997 ,998 ,999]` I mean you don't have to go through all the 200K items. You might say that may be not all of 0-999 are present in the big array. Then the best thing would be first to do `var uniques = [...new Set(inputArray)]` and call like `getCombosWithDiff(uniques,d)`. And you will get your result within 5 secs with Chrome or Node. Am i wrong..?

Comment: @duh So I just checked a 2M items array with items in range 1~1000 and a `d` value of 10 and it gets done within 5000msecs including the [...new Set(arr)]` (obtanining an array of unique values) stage. Once the `d` value gets bigger it gets shorter. Check [this](https://repl.it/ELZY/2)

Comment: @redus sorry for such a late reply, but I need to count the duplicate sets as well

Comment: @duh but what is the point of taking dupes into account since their pairs would result a difference of 0. Is zero going to be among the differences that you are searching for..?

Comment: @redus https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO15002 This is the complete question. Better explained there...

Answer (score 0):

Create a 1001-element array A of integers initialized to zeroes. Generate your random integers, and increment the appropriate index by 1 for each such integer. With some math, you could do this without generating 2,000,000 random integers, but it's not worth the complexity.

Create a second 1001-element integer B s.t. B[i] = A[0] + ... + A[i]

Answer is sum from i=0 to 1000-k of B[i] * (2,000,000 - B[i+k-1])